# Why is a second-child affected by my first-child color property?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I was finishing up selectors and testing my knowledge and encountered a problem that makes no sense.

In theory, the code below should color all first children that are `li` red, yet, a first and second child are being colored red.

Why is the second child colored red here?

```css
li:first-child{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Peter
        <ol>
            <li>Juan</li>
            <li>Samuel</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>John
        <ol>
            <li>Patrick</li>
            <li>Spongebob</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Sara
        <ol>
            <li>Jonathan</li>
            <li>Kragie</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`color` is inherited from the parent element....in this case the `li:first-child`

So when you tell the `li` to be a red color this is inherited by **all its children**.

You have no rule to override this for the children so they are colored *by inheritance*/

Answer (score 2):

It happens because the color is inherited from the parent element, try to add this to your CSS to override it:

```
li {
    color:initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have nested `li`s.

The second inner `li` is being coloured red because it's **inheriting** that rule from the style applied to the first child outer `li`, ie its parent.

```
li:first-child { color: red; }
li:not(:first-child) { color: black; }
```

That will override the inheritance and result in the text of the first outer **and** inner `li`s being red. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozqn1u4m/)

Alternatively, if you want to colour only the inner `li`s:

```
li li:first-child { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The li:first-child selector will also select the first li element in your parent list. You can target your selector using direct descendents or you can use classes.

## Option 1: class selector on parent list

This is the preferred option as it will automatically namespace your css. All your selectors will start with .menu when targeting child elements.

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Peter<ol>
        <li>Juan</li>
        <li>Samuel</li>
    </ol></li>
</ul>
```

```css
.menu ol li:first-child{
  color: red;
}
```

> If you want to override the style of a menu, you can use an extra class on the menu element and for example target it with the following selector. `.menu.horizontal`

## Option 2: class selector on list item

This option has the same benefits of the first option, but now .menuItem is namespaced on its own.

```html
<ul>
    <li class="menuItem">Peter<ol>
        <li>Juan</li>
        <li>Samuel</li>
    </ol></li>
</ul>
```

```css
.menuItem ol li:first-child{
  color: red;
}
```

## Option 3: direct descendent selector

```css
ol>li:first-child{
  color: red;
}
```

It is always better to use classes because if you use ol elements in other places, the selector would still apply there.